# wordpress bootstrap remove with margin left and right

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I`m using music macho theme for a wordpress website. The primary website (https://techtreetweb.000webhostapp.com/) is all fullwidth pictures. Now if i want to add extra pages those pages allways have a white margin to the left and right, as can be seen here (https://techtreetweb.000webhostapp.com/artistv2).
The website is very rudimenatary as of now and uses dummy pictures and images, because i want to solve this problem first before i move further. Please how can i make all following pages fullwidth ?  Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Search for the class **container** in your theme files and change it to **container-fluid**.

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Becomes:

```
<div class="container-fluid"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks I indeed found the container class and am trying to make the right adjustments